# Substitution number confusing

Tags: c#, regex

Here's the code:

```
string myVar = "00000";
string myPtrn = "(.).(...)";
string mySub = "$1" + "1" + "$2";
string myResult = Regex.Replace(myVar, myPtrn, mySub);
MessageBox.Show("Before :\t" + myVar + "\nAfter :\t" + myResult);
```

The result is `$11000`.

I'd like to have `01000` from `00000`.

But, I guess, `$1` is confused with `$11`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put capturing group number inside `{}` to avoid any confusion for regex engine like

```
string mySub = "${1}" + "1" + "$2";
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/lZfQr9)**

As suggested in comments, you can also use

```
string mySub = "${1}1$2";
```

Comment: which would be the same as `string mySub = "${1}1$2";`

Comment: @Mariano i believe, OP can do that

Comment: Probably so, but it's worth mentioning as I believe the OP was also confused thinking `"$1" + "1" + "$2"` would prevent it from interpreting it as `$11`, and there's no point in separating them in the code